# How to wrap each element in python list?

Tags: python

For example i have array like this:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

And i need to wrap it like this:

```
{'profile': '1', 'profile': '2', 'profile': '3', 'profile': '4'}
```

Tried something like this but with no luck:

```
result = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
result = {'profile': v for v in result}
```

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys in dictionary

Comment: @frostnational yeah, i this understood, but may be somehow possible to to this with other types?

Comment: @Kirix to do *what*? What are you trying to achieve here? How will you *use* this structure once you've figured out how to build it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construct

```
{'profile': '1', 'profile': '2', 'profile': '3', 'profile': '4'}
```

is Python-equivalent to

```
{'profile': '4'}
```

since, as noted, dictionaries cannot contain duplicate keys.  Hence **dictionaries are arguably not what your are looking for**.

What you can do is to use **[list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)**, as in

```
 >>> [('profile', x) for x in a]
 [('profile', '1'), ('profile', '2'), ('profile', '3'), ('profile', '4')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are not the structure you are looking for as they don't accept duplicate keys.

When you do  `result = {'profile': v for v in result}` you are overwriting `result['profile']` each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a dictionary with duplicate keys. But you can make a list of tuples. Using list comprehensions. See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

```
    [('profile', i) for i in ['1','2','3','4']]
```

Result

```
    [('profile', '1'), ('profile', '2'), ('profile', '3'), ('profile', '4')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map() to apply a function to each element of a list. However, as frostnational commented, you cannot have duplicate keys in a dictionary. If you want to have a dictionary for each element, you can do something like this (afterwards, you can pull each dictionary from the list):

```
>>> def wrap(x): return {"profile": x} 
>>> map(wrap, range(1,10))
[{'profile': 1}, {'profile': 2}, {'profile': 3}, {'profile': 4}, {'profile': 5},
{'profile': 6}, {'profile': 7}, {'profile': 8}, {'profile': 9}]
```